# File reading in C++

Tags: c++, file-processing

I am working on the image processing through c++, I has to read the header of jpeg image in char format, I has to check the camera/system/device information of image, how can i do it.

Comment: Is it really a file, or just raw data in a buffer?

Comment: Is you problem really about reading a file, or is it about how to find the meta data for the camera?  For meta data, you probably need to ask a much more specific question.

Comment: BTW, standard English sentences end with a period, '.', not a comma, ','.

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't too big, you can read it all into memory:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.bin", std::ios::binary);
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

const std::size_t filesize = infile.tellg();
std::vector<char> buf(filesize);

infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
infile.read(buf.data(), filesize);  // or &buf[0] on old compilers
```

Your file will be stored in the vector `buf`. If you only want to read the header, you can read smaller chunks, rather than all of `filesize`, and process them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the "meta" section of images are a fixed size.

Read the file, using `istream::read` and binary mode into a vector.  Using the image format specification, locate the field you need.

Build multibyte integers one byte a time, rather than trying to cast a location as an integer and reading.  This will help you overcome the issue of Endianness.